Separate selection with python
I'm trying to separate mesh in two parts with a script, I want to "cut" the mesh in a midpoint plane with bisec and than rip the vertices, this part of my script works fine, the problem is when I select all vertices that are above the bisec and perform a bpy.ops.mesh.separate(type='SELECTED'), only the vertex of the bisec was separated from the rest of the mesh, and not all the selection. Instead if I select the verteces manually(in the viewport)  the separate selection works well.

def bisect_and_select_inner_region(midpoint):
        
if bpy.context.object is None or bpy.context.object.type != 'MESH':
        print("Nessun oggetto mesh attivo selezionato.")
        return

    if bpy.context.mode != 'EDIT_MESH':
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')

    obj = bpy.context.edit_object
    mesh = obj.data
    bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(mesh)
    
    # Perform Bisec
    bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT')
    bpy.ops.mesh.bisect(plane_co=(0, midpoint, 0), plane_no=(0, -1, 0), clear_inner=False, clear_outer=False, use_fill=False)
    
    original_type = bpy.context.area.type
    bpy.context.area.type = "VIEW_3D"
    
    # Rip vertices
    bpy.ops.mesh.rip()
    bpy.context.area.type = original_type
    
    # Select vertex above the bisec
    for v in bm.verts:
        if v.co.y > midpoint:
            v.select = True

    # Separate select
    bpy.ops.mesh.separate(type='SELECTED')
    
    
    bmesh.update_edit_mesh(mesh)


I believe the specification is that the result of using bpy.ops.mesh.bisect will select the cut surface of the mesh. Therefore, if you want to bisect an object, you can copy the object beforehand. The destination object is the opposite of the bisect method.

If you interact with a bmesh via python script you have to call update_edit_mesh before you do any regular bpy.ops operations. Also you might need to experiment with running bm.select_flush/select_flush_mode to make sure that your programmatic selection updates correctly.
